# Configuring log4net in unit tests to log to console and display proper date and time

Tags: c#, .net, log4net, log4net-configuration

I am running some unit tests, and I would like log4net to log everything to the Console (just for inspection). Following the manual, I used:

```
BasicConfigurator.Configure();
```

However, this sets up the logging pattern to `%-4timestamp [%thread] %-5level %logger %ndc - %message%newline`. How can I change it so that instead of the timestamp I get the usual date and time (up to miliseconds)?

Comment: Simply add an `App.config` to your test project and define whatever pattern you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get ConsoleAppender from logger repository and change it's layout:

```
BasicConfigurator.Configure();
var appender = LogManager.GetRepository()
                         .GetAppenders()
                         .OfType<ConsoleAppender>()
                         .First();

appender.Layout = new PatternLayout("%d %-5level %logger - %m%n"); // set pattern
ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(logger_name); // obtain logger
```

But configuration via config file is preferred way, because you can change settings without recompiling your tests.

Comment: I understand the rationale for using config files in general and I'm a huge fan of unit testing, but I'm honestly struggling to see a use case for running unit tests without recompiling. Under what circumstances would you - or indeed _could_ you - run your unit tests without recompiling but having changed config files? Perhaps I'm missing something, but I don't see unit tests as static binaries that you re-run with a config change, rather they are more like dynamic entities, which indeed _rely_ on rebuilding to make sure they are still _currently_ valid.

Comment: @stuartd agree, with unit-tests changing code and recompiling really not significant. The only case I can imagine is running unit-tests on some continuous integration tool like Jenkins. QA can go to server and change settings in config file without modifying code. But in this particular case I agree, configuration file does not have any benefits